# App crashes after 4 minutes

Tags: iphone, crash, arc4random

I'm getting a strange crash during an arc4random call that only appears after about 4 minutes of the app running, and it doesn't do it every time. Here's the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 25C8C57F-0434-40B2-A2E8-FE88F58ABF60
CrashReporter Key:   8683ce910e9db4ba69f61266b606396f941d08ee
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-01-16 18:46:45.170 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148a)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
<App> failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 5.930 (user 5.380, system 0.550), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 4.790, 81% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31168006 pthread_mutex_lock + 50
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3118cb10 arc4random + 24
2   <App>                   0x0000f658 -[BasicGameLayer updateBoard] (BasicGameScreen.mm:318)
3   <App>                    0x00010790 -[BasicGameLayer handleTouches:withEvent:] (BasicGameScreen.mm:238)
4   <App>                   0x0000e504 -[BasicGameLayer ccTouchesBegan:withEvent:] (BasicGameScreen.mm:276)
```

Line 318 of BasicGameScreen.mm is an opening brace. I'm assuming the compiler is removing whitespace so I think the line it's crashing on is

```
int selection = arc4random() % 16;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an infinite loop (in my code) that was triggered under a very specific combination of variables.

Answer (score 4):

The clue is here:

> Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d

It means that something you're doing on startup is taking too long to finish executing.